# Viewing content of a binary field in PHPMyAdmin page

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was asked to take a look at an old database and export the data within a table, but the fields are I believe in binary, but look like the city and state fields in the picture. [image] I clicked Edit and found that they were considered binary fields, but wasn't sure how to get the text from them. [image]When I export the information it looks like a ton of special characters. Is there any way to convert this to regular text? I'm not familiar to what this is hosted on, but I have used sql before. Any help would be appreciated!